# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django

I keep on getting this error whenever I run my server locally.
This is how allowed hosts is in my .env file  ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
I have tried adding '127.0.0.1' to the .env file instead of * but nothing seems to be working.Any ideas?

Comment: "_in my .env_" well what is it set to in your _`settings.py`_ file?

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS=ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())

Answer (score 4):

Django doesn't read .env file by itself. You should care about it.

If you want Django reading environment variables, you should use `os.environ.get()` method at your `settings.py`. But environment variables must be available for django. Export it at command line or provide .env file to your docker container.

Also, you can use this library: https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS=ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())    this is how it is my settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by editing settings.py file. Add the IP address without the port number to the ALLOWED_HOSTS array thus:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

This solved my problem.